# Python Pandas : How to select two equal column per row of a dataframe

Tags: python, select, indexing, pandas, group-by

Here is my dataframe 'dfm':

```
match   org_o                         group 
012       012 Smile Communications     92   
012       012 Smile                    92   
10types   10TYPES                      93   
10types   10types.com                  93   
360works  360WORKS                     94   
360works  360works.com                 94   
400 IBM   AS/400 Division              36   
6c f3f    IBM Internal US Division     36
```

and I want to select rows with the same 'group'  number as well as same 'match'. So the result would look like this:

```
   match    org_o                         group 
    012       012 Smile Communications     92   
    012       012 Smile                    92   
    10types   10TYPES                      93   
    10types   10types.com                  93   
    360works  360WORKS                     94   
    360works  360works.com                 94
```

Anybody knows how can I do it in python pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` on 'group' and 'match' and then `filter` on the count of 'org_o' > 1:

```
In [245]:

df.groupby(['group', 'match']).filter(lambda x: x['org_o'].count() > 1)
Out[245]:
      match                     org_o  group
0       012  012 Smile Communications     92
1       012                 012 Smile     92
2   10types                   10TYPES     93
3   10types               10types.com     93
4  360works                  360WORKS     94
5  360works              360works.com     94
```